# Compare variables in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way in .htaccess to compare `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` value with `%{QUERY_STRING}` value, if they match then redirect accordin to?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}  .*regex%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule .* http://somewhere-else/ [R]
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, Can you guide me bit about using varibables, lik in http_cookie i have to use PHPSESSID and Query_String I need to only toke=something, not all query strings? I am new to .htaccess

Comment: i would recommend doing this in a real scripting language (in your cas php). also there i sno reliable way to get the php session id. you can only work with string matching which is not usable for url parsing. also session ids can be passed via cookies.

Comment: actually I have session maitian on another domain, and all requests need to be redirected to checking domain, if they allow they clinet should view page, so, I need to compare querty string sent by checking domain, and cookie stored in client side, and then decide to redirect or not, please help

Comment: sorry i do not understand completely. you should post a follow up question describing your exact use case, i am sure you will recieve good feedback. i also believe that solving this in htaccess alone will not be the best way to go.

Comment: Actually there are two domain, one is abc.com and one is xyz.com, all requests from abc.com are redirected to xyz.com, xyz.com have a page check.php, which check if the request is accessable or not, if not it sends to no_access.php but if access is allowed it send back to requested page, but .htaccess send back again to check.php which creates an infinite loop, to stop this I am trying different option, please suggest if there a secure way to do in .htaccess